# how can I fetch a string from a single json value and append it to my label in swift (using alamofire)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a json with a structure:

```
{"numberOfPeople":120}
```

I want to build a label in swift that contains the following string:

```
We had seen there more than <<numberOfPeople fetched from json>> adults
```

This is what I am doing so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfHelpersLabel: UILabel!
var text = "We had seen there more than "
var text2 = " adults"


Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://webservice.com/getnumber")
    .responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                let numberOfPeople = json["numberOfPeople"].description
                self.numberOfHelpersLabel.text = self.text+numberOfPeople + self.text2

            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("SWITCH ERROR")
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

but it doesn't work, the error says:

[image]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called String interpolation. Inside a string you can put an expression inside an escaped parenthesis `\()`. Like this:

```
self.numberOfHelpersLabel.text = "We had seen there more than \(numberOfPeople) adults"
```

(The first error looks weird, I see no optional chaining in that line, I'd advice you to clean and rebuild.)

Answer (score 1):

As the values in the `JSON` object are *optionals* you need to unwrap them (hence the error about recommending the usage of `String?`).

The other error is as the JSON accessed property, `numberOfPeople` could be *anything*, the compiler doesn't know how to concatenate the Strings together, so you need to add a hint that it will be a String.

These two issues together can be done a few ways... a simple example:

```
if let value = response.result.value {
    let json = JSON(value)

    if json["numberOfPeople"] != nil {
        let numberOfPeople = json["numberOfPeople"] as? String

        // your original string concatenation would then work
        //self.numberOfHelpersLabel.text = self.text + numberOfPeople + self.text2

        // or a bit cleaner using interpolation:
        self.numberOfHelpersLabel.text = "We had seen there more than \(numberOfPeople) adults"
    }      
} else {
    self.numberOfHelpersLabel.text = "Wow no idea how many people!"
}
```